# How to override controller helper method loaded from a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have a situation where I am trying to avoid changing hundreds of rails views that call a helper method (**page_title**) loaded from a gem. I want to create a helper *with the exact same name* (page_title). Then, within this new page_title helper, I want to check a condition; if the condition is **true**, I want to perform some logic and if it's **false**, **I want to execute the  page_title helper loaded from the gem.**

In our views, we're calling **page_title** (loaded from a gem):

```
<%= page_title domain: "Leasing", page: "Guest Cards" %>
```

The gem loads this module...

```
module OsmUiHelper
  ...
  def page_title(options = {})
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

...like this...

```
module OsmUi
  module Rails
    class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
      ...
      config.to_prepare do
        ApplicationController.helper(OsmUiHelper)
      end
    ...
  end
end
```

I've tried all sorts of gymnastics trying to get this to work and all have failed. My latest attempt was trying to alias the page_title method in the gem to old_page_title in the hope that when my page_title helper (see below) is loaded, it would override page_title in the gem and all would be good, but the old page_title in the gem is being called:

```
# /controllers/helper/page_title_helper.rb
module Controllers
  module PageTitleHelper
    def page_title(options = {})
      company_id = settings ? settings.company_id : 0
      if Feature.on?('omnibar_enabled', company_id)
        # Use my page_title logic here
      else
        # Use the gem page_title aliased as old_page_title (see below)
        old_page_title(options)
      end
    end
  end
end

# /rails/lib/osm_ui_helper_patch.rb
require 'osm_ui_helper'

module OsmUiHelper
  alias_method :old_page_title, :page_title
end
```

How can I get this to work? Is there anyway to manipulate the helpers directly in ApplicationController.helpers perhaps? I'm at my wits end.

Thanks in advance.

**SOLUTION**

This solved my issue. Simple:

```
# /rails/app/helpers/controllers/page_title_helper.rb

module Controllers
  module PageTitleHelper
    include OsmUiHelper

    alias old_page_title page_title

    # rubocop:disable Style/OptionHash
    def page_title(options = {})
      company_id = settings ? settings.company_id : 0
      if Feature.on?('omnibar_enabled', company_id)
        # New logic here
      else
        # Use the old page_title in the gem
        old_page_title(options)
      end
    end
    # rubocop:enable Style/OptionHash
  end
end
```

Comment: I think you want to do this via ActiveSupport::Concern - https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/engines.html#overriding-models-and-controllers  https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.7/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html

Comment: @tgmerritt that did it, thank you. Post it and I'll select it as the answer.

Comment: @tgmerritt actually seems I didn't need concerns at all, just needed to do what I specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved my issue. Simple:

```
# /rails/app/helpers/controllers/page_title_helper.rb

module Controllers
  module PageTitleHelper
    include OsmUiHelper

    alias old_page_title page_title

    # rubocop:disable Style/OptionHash
    def page_title(options = {})
      company_id = settings ? settings.company_id : 0
      if Feature.on?('omnibar_enabled', company_id)
        # New logic here
      else
        # Use the old page_title in the gem
        old_page_title(options)
      end
    end
    # rubocop:enable Style/OptionHash
  end
end
```